# Keyboard shortcut to sync in GitHub Desktop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, github-desktop

Is there any keyboard shortcut to sync in GitHub Desktop? Hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after writing a commit comment creates a commit, but I wonder how to sync without using the mouse.

Answer (score 6):

To sync without using the mouse, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In the mac-verse, to sync without using the mouse, press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

(IURI:committing is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)